# Generating Certificates in iOS Provisioning Portal doesn't work

Tags: ios, ios5, certificate, provisioning, portal

I can't create Developer or either Distribution certificates anymore after revoked the old one.

I'm using the latest xCode 4.3.1 and running osX lion 10.7.3

Does anybody know why my certificate dissapears after uploading my signing authority?
Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

[Apparently its a wide spread issue](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3799289?tstart=0)